# numbers want to cross a river, but their sum must be a square number

Tags: optimization, river-crossing

In the world of numbers, numbers 1 to 9 want to cross a river,
They have a boat which can take 1 to 3 numbers,
But sum of the numbers must be a square number.
The boat can not sail back itself, so there must be some numbers to sail back.

Plan minimum number of trips in such a way that all the numbers can cross the river.

[image]

I use Microsoft Clip art organizer to search the individual pictures (boat and man) then compose the picture.

Comment: Just a minor note - your sails are hovering over the boat without being attached.

Comment: @boboquack maybe number land is highly technological and they invented levitating sails 0_0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minimum is

> 7 crossings

This is achieved by:

> Send 2+5+9 = 16
>  Bring back 9
>  Send 3+4+9 = 16
>  Bring back 9
>  Send 1+7+8 = 16
>  Bring back 1
>  Send 1+6+9 = 16

Answer (score 2):

The minimum is

> 9.
>  The largest possible square that is the sum of 3 numbers is 16.
>  Therefore the only trips are 16, 9, 4, and 1. which can be done with the following:
>  First take 9, 5, 2, and bring back the 9.
>  Then take 8, 7, 1, and bring back 7, 2.
>  Next take 9, 7, and bring back the 9 again.
>  On the fourth trip over, take 9, 4, 3, and bring back the 1.
>  Finally take over the 6, 2, 1.

Comment: The boat can not sail back itself.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya fixed.

Comment: +1 for your effort, but sp3000 have the minimum trip.